# Remove specific product from Solr core while deleting product in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, flat-catalog, solr

Is there any better way to deleting the product from Solr core while deleting the product from Magento admin.

When I delete a product , it doesn't actually reflected or removed the product from Solr core. So, Even I can able to view the deleted product in the autosuggest result.

Could anyone have an idea or solution about how to handle these scenarios?

### Solution Found

- By using below solr query (Refer image or Referral link), we can remove the specific product from Solr core.

[image: Solr Query]

[Referral Link](https://gist.github.com/nz/673027/313f70681daa985ea13ba33a385753aef951a0f3)

Comment: please reindex your catalog data

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Even though reindex catalog data and doing solr indexing the product still present in Solr core. I need to remove the specific product from Solr core.

Comment: I found the solution for my self. Updated my question with solution